# what does \eval "$__conda_setup" actually do?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am having to track down an environmental issue with wxpython. I am curious how someone would poke around the os to find the location of the code that ensues here when executes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377460/why-escape-the-first-character-of-eval-in-profile-script) explains the backslash but I am more concerned of looking at what it is actually evaluating and where it is getting this from.

More context:

I encountered what I believe to be the issues around configuration of terminal path execution within VSCode (combined with conda setup from my .bash_profile). I am still investigating this. I was presented a Python framework error similar to but not exactly like Mark Needham's [post](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2018/05/04/python-runtime-error-osx-matplotlib-not-installed-as-framework-mac/) which he ended up suggesting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977388/matplotlib-runtimeerror-python-is-not-installed-as-a-frameworkCurrently) as a matplotlib fix. My error (I'm 85% certain) revolves around my Homebrew install of Python into my cloned from base conda environment. Heres why:

I tracked my framework error by looking at the output of `python --version` from within vscode:

```sh
$ which python
# /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
python --version
# Python 3.7.4
```

and then from a terminal launch from spotlight search on my MBP (I'm still a little green on Mac products), which showed the latter to be running

```sh
$ which python
/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/wx_test_env/bin/python
(wx_test_env) my-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

Lesson here may be on understanding how the \eval works in your bash profile, but I am trying to correlate (finally) why a few of the advanced tutorials speak of using Iterm2 with VSCode instead of the defaults here. I could use a tutorial on that configuration, for sure (along with a short and sweet synopsis).

I was also informed that some people like to pull out their conda init lines from their .bash* setup into an easily accessed or executed script to deal with switching between versions, but I felt like that was kind of defeating the purpose of an IT governance solution like conda in the first place. If anyone has a python solution to something similar and an explanation of how they believe it solves their situation I would love to understand their perspective further.

Thank you the comment of profile helps. I am not giving up on the script it as I need it approach that another friend of mine named Seth offered me from Apple, he does UI frontend work mainly in JS so I had to take his suggestion with a grain of salt. I am looking for ways to easily jump in and out of environements as needed from a systems perspective, and yes, with a primary focus Python, However I am getting better at understanding generators, gRPC's and being able to launch from a yaml file, so the script here will be to parse the environment in the context of where I may be debugging from and then choose an appropriate conda activate command to suit. It's still a little hazy for now, but I will look into your suggestion. Thanks again, I thought you might be him trolling me at first glance as we had a very paralleled conversation on the topic right before posting the original question.

Comment: Describing your environmental issue is probably more helpful. Otherwise you will need to dig into the documentation of that specific piece of software.

Comment: What specific "conda" software are you using? A dependency management solution (first result using "conda python") is not an IT governance solution. It is merely a dependency management tool.

Comment: https://www.anaconda.com/governance/ . I will have to relook at this entire post as I have lost steam and do not even know what my reason was for posting this in the first place:)

Comment: Oh, yeah. I wanted to see if I could actually get answers faster here on subject matter than looking for the answers myself. Thats why I don't ask many questions in forums, but I think A burger King mentality doesn't always work. Sometimes its good to ask the community and other times is good just to stimulate intellectual conversation:)

Comment: You may be thinking of conda in this [context](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/download.html#anaconda-or-miniconda) with just python and a minimal use case, bringing in packages as one needs them individually. I do like the switch around for multiple projects quickly and efficiently, however. I'm just having trouble convincing myself to just do it with a separate script. I'm trying to get the hang of letting the tooling and people behind the designing of them work for me, but to each their own. Some like a quick fix to annoying situation.

Comment: Are you using the Enterprise edition? If so consider asking their support. Your research so far already shows that you have multiple Python environments that are probably configured using profiles. Anaconda is probably not installed/added to each of those profiles. So if you want it to be available in each you'd have to either add it manually or find a global configuration file for it. I don't know MacOS and Python well enough for that but it might be a good direction to look into.